# Python : Dictionary and .format

Tags: python

could someone help me understand why this works and the latter does not?
For instance,

```
def main():
    diction = {"DDL":"Defined Data Language","EDW":"Enterprise Data Warehouse","ACID": "Atomicity,Consistency,Isolation,Durability"}
    TEST=diction.get("DDL")
    
print(" Meaning:{}".format(TEST))
```

The above code works however if I make the variable `TEST = diction[0]` the code fails. Could anyone explain this to me?

P.S. the error is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text\Python_Executables\second_mod.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text\Python_Executables\second_mod.py", line 4, in main
    TEST=diction[0]
KeyError: 0
[Finished in 80ms]
```

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are dealing with dictionaries and they are made of set of key,values and you can get the value by given keys and not with indexes.

But if you must get a value using index , you can convert the dictionary to list :

```
TEST = list(diction.values())[0]
```

Comment: @TheFool values() return `<class 'dict_values'>`. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Python Dictionary items are accessed using key name, index can't be used. In your example, 0 is considered as a key. Since it is not in the dictionary diction, code throw KeyError

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered, you can't get key value by index, you can only get key value by key name, example: `TEST = diction["DDL"]`

Comment: Careful dictionaries are ordered in current versions of python3

Answer (score 0):

It throws an error because you are trying to get the value of the dictionary identified by the key `0`. Yet, you don't have any `0` in your dictionary.

It would work if you included it.

```
diction = {"DDL":"Defined Data Language",
           "EDW":"Enterprise Data Warehouse",
           "ACID": "Atomicity,Consistency,Isolation,Durability",
            0: 'something'
        }
```

In conclusion, you can only call elements by their key, if you are dealing with dictionaries in Python, not by their index position, as you would do with a list or tuple. Therefore, the possibilities you have are the following; everything else will fail.

```
diction['DDL']
diction['EDW']
diction['ACID']
```

Comment: Thank you , I really appreciated the help!